# Python 3, преобразование JSON-списка в словарь

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Доброго времени суток. Возник вопрос. 
Пишу код для сбора информации по группе ВК. VK-API возвращает ответ в виде списка. Есть необходимость преобразовать JSON-список в словарь. Как, собственно, это сделать?
Вот код:

```
import vk                                                                                  
import csv                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          



session = vk.Session()                                                                     
api = vk.API(session)                                                                      

with open('current_groups_2.csv', 'r') as file1:                                           
        reader = csv.reader(file1)                                                             
        reader = map(int, file1)                                                               
        group_list = list(reader)                                                              


    while True:                                                                                
        for slonik in group_list:                                                              
            if slonik <= max(group_list):                                                      
                pahom = api.groups.getById(group_id=slonik, fields='members_count', c=3)       
                members = api.groups.getMembers(group_id=slonik, offset=10, c=3)               
                print(sorted(pahom))                                                           
                '\n'                                                                           
                print(members)                                                                 
                '\n'                                                                                                                                                                         
        break
```

Вот пример вывода (возвращает два списка):

```
[{'name': '7 ноября | 7teaQUIZ - Интеллектуальная игра', 'photo_medium': 'https://pp.vk.me/c836337/v836337144/8806/MHu2rdmOWrk.jpg', 'type': 'event', 'photo': 'https://pp.vk.me/c836337/v836337144/8807/g9D3aPUWRCw.jpg', 'screen_name': 'game7teaquiz', 'is_closed': 0, 'gid': 130813158, 'photo_big': 'https://pp.vk.me/c836337/v836337144/8805/SKd08w3JXVw.jpg', 'members_count': 64}]
{'users': [4616143, 4905583, 5020621, 5075553, 5719830, 6521609, 6656144, 6743475, 6878853, 6943270, 8038966, 8108192, 9020689, 9101839, 9211246, 10642427, 10724272, 11801515, 12339179, 14266378, 14295344, 14733893, 14793302, 15130472, 16634252, 17035575, 17887594, 18730151, 18793031, 19008985, 25636676, 25876136, 28615796, 36896731, 39429003, 39460947, 41406500, 50029265, 53856532, 57557645, 59190909, 63664469, 71634261, 77884116, 97559394, 111169501, 135846191, 153807112, 173184651, 205318641, 225583392, 241450237, 312577254, 320475790], 'count': 64}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
...
result = json.loads(сюда пишем json строку)
```

Подключите модуль `json`(он встроен в Python), в нем есть практически все для работы с данными в этом формате. Функция `loads` вернет Python-объект, исходя из того, что лежит в `JSON`'е. Вот привожу таблицу преобразования, для наглядности:

[image: conversion table]