# как преобразовать json в словарь python?

Tags: python, json

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую библиотеку и как нужно использовать для того, чтобы преобразовать JSON в словарь, а лучше в список? Вот пример

```
{'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
'range': 'Sheet1!B2:B1000',
'values': [['Имя1'], ['Имя2']]}
```

По итогу мне нужно получать лишь элементы Имя1, Имя2

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python 3, преобразование JSON-списка в словарь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585982/python-3-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-json-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c)

Comment: @EzikBro видимо я что то делаю не так, но задав переменную index = json.loads(index_real), где index_real - json объект, я получил ошибку TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: @MaxZhukov Если у вас уже есть JSON объект, то его не надо грузить, он уже есть. Откуда вы его взяли?

Comment: @CrazyElf я получил данные через Google API:  index_real = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
    range='B2:B',
    majorDimension='ROWS'
).execute()

Comment: @MaxZhukov, судя по ошибке из комментария вы пытаетесь передать `json.loads()` словарь в качестве аргумента для того чтобы преобразовать __уже словарь__ в словарь?? ;) Таким образом решением будет: `result = index_real` :-D

Answer (score 0):

У вас в примере не совсем JSON, на него ругается конвертер из-за одинарных кавычек. Вот так получилось загрузить:

```
import json
    
print(json.loads("""{'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
'range': 'Sheet1!B2:B1000',
'values': [['Имя1'], ['Имя2']]}""".replace("'", '"'))['values'])
```

Вывод:

```
[['Имя1'], ['Имя2']]
```